# Программа для выдачи прав по логину и паролю. (c++)

Tags: c++

Здравствуйте. Есть задача: "
В компьютерной системе зарегистрировано несколько пользователей. Разработать программу, которая будет определять сможет пользователь получить доступ к чтению (r), записи (w) или выполнение файлов (x), на основе имени учетной записи пользователя".
У меня есть готовый код проверки логина и пароля. Но проблема в том, что он подходит только для одного логина.
Как поместить сюда еще логины, и как сделать разные сообщения для разных пользователей?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string login = "Alice";
    string password = "Bobly";
    string log1;
    string pass;
    for (int i=0; i<3; i++)
    {
        cout << i+1 << "Enter login:";
        cin >> log1;
        if (log1 == login)
        {
            cout << "Login accepted, enter password:" << endl;
            cin >> pass;
            if (pass == password)
            {
                cout << "Welcome!";
                return 0;
            }
            else
                cout << "Access denied!";
                return 0;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: вы хотите реализовать аналог: `sudo -u <username> [ -x <filename>  ] ; echo $?` ?

Comment: Нет. При правильном вводе пароля должно быть написано какие права для файла доступны пользователю. По типу: для пользователя Alice доступны права rw rw rw, а для Bob - r r r. По сути, после успешного входа Alice будет написано сообщения что доступны такие права, а для Bob - такие.

Comment: что вы думаете, команда, которую я привёл делает?

Comment: Вы хотите это сделать для какой-то реальной ОС (например, Linux)  или для собственной модели доступа? Если для собственной, то опишите ее поподробнее

Comment: Что-то типа этого. Для собственной модели доступа разумеется. Т.е. типа той команды которую вы написали.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот вариант проверки нескольких учетных записей. Если Вам надо было скорректировать приведенный в вопросе код - то можно так. А если Вас интересует команда в терминале для определения прав пользователей, то `sudo ...` вам в помощь (см. комментарий jfs).

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <utility>
#include <cstdint>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <string>
#include <map>

using index_t = std::uint64_t;

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    const index_t N = 3; // Number of attempts

    std::map< std::string, std::pair< std::string, std::string > > m;

    m.emplace(std::make_pair(std::string("Alice"),
              std::make_pair(std::string("1234"),
                             std::string("Hello, Alice! You can: [rw, rw, rw]"))));

    m.emplace(std::make_pair(std::string("Bob"),
              std::make_pair(std::string("5678"),
                             std::string("Hello, Bob! You can: [r, r, r]"))));

    std::string login, password;

    for (index_t i = 0; i < N; ++i)
    {
        std::cout << "Enter login #" << i + 1 << ": ";
        std::cin >> login;

        auto login_iterator = m.find(login);

        if (login_iterator != std::end(m))
        {
            std::cout << "Enter password: ";
            std::cin >> password;

            if (login_iterator->second.first == password)
                std::cout << login_iterator->second.second << std::endl;
            else
                std::cout << "Error: wrong password." << std::endl;
        }
        else
            std::cout << "Error: login \"" << login << "\" not found." << std::endl;
    }

    system("pause");

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Если у пользователя потребуется хранить дополнительную информацию, кроме пароля и строки со списком прав, то элемент контейнера надо заменить с `pair` на пользовательскую структуру и обращаться к полям этой структуры...

Comment: К вам человек пришел с проблемой `2+2`, а вы ему про интегралы втираете :)

Comment: @ffk Птенцы учатся летать падая из гнезда.

Answer (score 1):

*Используйте вектор по умолчанию (А. Александреску)*

Создайте массив логинов, а еще лучше ассоциативный контейнер `map`, в котором в качестве ключа храните `login`, а в качестве значения - пару `std::pair` :

{ пароль; индивидуальное сообщение для логина }.

При вводе логина пользуйтесь стандартной функцией данного ассоциативного контейнера `find(key)`, которая возвращает итератор на соответствующий элемент в контейнере с ключом, указанным в качестве аргумента, и итератор `end`, если ключ отсутствует. Прочитать об этой функции можно, например, [здесь](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/find). Описание контейнера `map` можно найти [здесь](http://ru.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map).

Далее, у Вас элемент контейнера - вышеуказанная пара. Получаете доступ к полю с паролем через `.first`, сравниваете, получаете доступ к полю с сообщением через `.second`. С описанием `pair` можете ознакомиться, например, [здесь](http://ru.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/pair).